# Checking disk status (Behind raid card) from bash

Tags: linux, raid

We have a SuperMicro server with LSI Raid Controller. Is there a way to get any kind of information related to disks on raid controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MegaCLI tool is able to communicate with the controller and retrieve such information.